# how to compute image retrieval time in matlab

Tags: matlab, time

I am working on image retrieval system, in order to evaluate the performance of CBIR we should compute the retrieval time..I used the bulit-in-function tic and toc function; I saw it give me different times each run and I saw some time that it summation the time from run  to run..I made many trying to compute the retrieval time for each retrieval, for example I saved the retrieval time (it is mean the toc contain) in one variable say timeR=toc, then I timeR=0 for next retrieval...

```
timeR=o;
tic;

% image retrieval process

toc;

timR=toc;
```

Still I get different times..Please any one help me on how can I compute the retrieval time for each query image, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the code for retrieval performs slightly different for each image.
In order to get better understanding of your running time I suggest you use Matlab's profiling tools.

```
 profile clear;
 profile on; 
 % your code here
 profile off;
 profile viewer;
```

Using profiler you can see what takes time in your code.

Moreover, in your code snippet, you calls `toc` twice, this might cause some of the bizarre behavior you are experiencing.

for a more specific measures, you may try

```
rTimes = zeros(1, numMethods);
% prepare images and what ever you need ...
for imi = 1:numImages
    % read test image ...
    tic;
    % use your method for ret.
    rTimes(1) = rTimes(1) + toc; % add this run time to your counter


    tic;
    % here you run method 2 that you want to compare to...
    rTimes(2) = rTimes(2) + toc; % add run time for method 2

    % do the same for all methods ...

    tic;
    % run the numMethods-th method
    rTimes(numMethods) = rTimes(numMethods) + toc;
end
% now rTimes hold the running times (overall) for all methods over all test images.
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.. I need the total retrieval time in order to compare between retrieval methods.. this code give me more details that I didn't need it and what is the actual retrieval time from the profile table.

Comment: thank you for replying... may be you didn't understand my question .. Firstly, I need to compute the retrieval time for each feature or method that I used it in my project, for example I want to compute the retrieval time using color histogram and color moment features then compare between the retrieval time for each feature, another example I want to compare between retrieval time using linear and non-linear method and so on..I didn't need the overall running time for all methods over all test images. regards

Comment: @zenab - I understand you need to measure different times for different segments of your code. I think the above example gives you the tools you need to accomplish that. The answers here are not meant to do your task instead of you, but rather help you succeed in doing your task on your own.